# how to Show a button in form view only in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

how to Show a button in form view, when in view mode, and hide in edit and create mode in odoo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `oe_read_only` class, eg.:

```xml
<button name="my_action" type="object" string="Do foo" class="oe_read_only"/>
```

Comment: Its not working for me i have tried to hide a field in edit mode and display in view mode.